# Selling access to web apps stored in S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3

I have several Rise 360 courses that I have exported to web apps and added them to my S3 bucket.  I want to know the best was that I can sell access to these web apps from my website which I have built on the WordPress platform.  I currently have 10 web apps in one bucket.
I don't want people to be able to take the URL and post it somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Content in Amazon S3 is **private by default**. Access is only available if you grant access in some way.

A good way to grant access to private content is to use [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). These grant *temporary access* to private objects.

The flow would work something like this:

- A user purchases a course
- They then access a "My Courses" page
- When generating that page, the PHP code would consult a database to determine what courses they have purchased
- For each course they are allowed to access, the PHP code will **generate a pre-signed URL** to the course in Amazon S3. The URL can be configured to provide access for a period of time, such as 30 minutes
- The user follows that URL and access the course. (**Note:** This assumes that only a single object is accessed.)
- Once the expiry time is passed, the object is no longer accessible. The user would need to return to the "My Courses" page and click a newly-generated link to access the course again

If a user extracts the URL from the page, they **will be able to download the object**. You say *"I don't want people to be able to take the URL and post it somewhere."* This is not possible to guarantee because the app *is* granting them access to the object. However, that access will be time-limited so if they share the URL, it will stop working after a while.

If your app requires access to more than one URL (eg if the first page refers to a second page), then this method will not work. Instead, users will need to access the content *via your app*, with the app checking their access every time rather than allowing users to access the content directly from S3.